# How to form a new array by ADDING Element having Same Date in A PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

Consider a array called $salay

```
Array
(
      [0] => Array
        (
          [created_date] => 2020-10-23 00:00:00
          [salary] => 12000
        )
      [1] => Array
        (
          [created_date] => 2020-10-24 00:00:00
          [salary] => 1500
        )
      [2] => Array
        (
          [created_date] => 2020-11-11 00:00:00
          [salary] => 500
        )
      [3] => Array
         (
           [created_date] => 2020-11-11 00:00:00
           [salary] => 500
         )
      [4] => Array
         (
           [created_date] => 2020-11-12 00:00:00
           [salary] => 2000
         )
     
 )
```

i am trying to

- check repeated created_date in array
- if repeated dates present in array then add salary and push to new array called $result[] in the form of ('created_date'=>repeated_date,'salary'=>added_salary.
- if not present then directly push to $result[];

The $result array look like

```
    Array
    (
          [0] => Array
            (
              [created_date] => 2020-10-23 00:00:00
              [salary] => 12000
            )
          [1] => Array
            (
              [created_date] => 2020-10-24 00:00:00
              [salary] => 1500
            )
          [2] => Array
            (
              [created_date] => 2020-11-11 00:00:00
              [salary] => 1000
            )
         
          [3] => Array
             (
               [created_date] => 2020-11-12 00:00:00
               [salary] => 2000
             )
         
     )
```

thanks,

Comment: In your steps, you have described the algorithm, convert it to code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this solution :

```
$result = [];
$salaries = [
        ["created_date" => "2020-10-23 00:00:00", "salary" => 12000],
        ["created_date" => "2020-10-24 00:00:00", "salary" => 1500],
        [ "created_date" => "2020-11-11 00:00:00", "salary" => 500],
        ["created_date" => "2020-11-11 00:00:00", "salary" => 500],
        ["created_date" => "2020-11-12 00:00:00", "salary" => 2000]
      ]; 

foreach($salaries as $key =>$value){
         if(isset($result[$value['created_date']])){
            $result[$value['created_date']]['salary']+=$value['salary'];
           }else{
            $result[$value['created_date']]['created_date'] =$value['created_date'];
            $result[$value['created_date']]['salary'] =$value['salary'];
            }
}
sort($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this solution. Hope this will solve your problem. It will check the date and time both (as your format `2020-10-23 00:00:00`).

```
$salaries = [
        ["created_date" => "2020-10-23 00:00:00", "salary" => 12000],
        ["created_date" => "2020-10-24 00:00:00", "salary" => 1500],
        [ "created_date" => "2020-11-11 00:00:00", "salary" => 500],
        ["created_date" => "2020-11-11 00:00:00", "salary" => 500],
        ["created_date" => "2020-11-12 00:00:00", "salary" => 2000]
      ]; 

$result = [];

function checkDuplicateIndex($result, $date) {
  $index = -1;
  for($i= 0; $i<count($result); $i++) {
     if (strtotime($result[$i]['created_date']) == strtotime($date)) {
        $index = $i; 
        break;
     }
  }
  return $index;
 }

foreach($salaries as $salary) {
    $index = checkDuplicateIndex($result, $salary['created_date']);
    if ($index == -1) {
        array_push($result, $salary);
    } else {
        $result[$index]['salary'] = $result[$index]['salary'] + $salary['salary'];
    }
}
```